# How to get additional Information with ActivityManager

Tags: android, android-activity

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
                componentInfo.getPackageName();

                activity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
                packagename = componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

I have this code to get the running activity and package names. My question is:
This package contains another class (Name.java), which is not an activity and returns a String Value that I also need to get.
Is this possible with the ActivityManager?

To be more clear:
the home activity is a screen with a list of items. by sliding to the right or to the left, the screen changes and displays, for example, favorite items, rated items etc. each of those screens/views have a name (Name.java handles it). What I want to do is, to get the name of the current view also, not just the name of the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't get this information using the ActivityManager. The ActivityManager will only give you information about Android components (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvider) and their configuration. You can't access random Java classes within other packages.

Comment: thank you.is there any other way to get this information though?

Comment: No. You are going about this the wrong way. Maybe you can have your "home activity" broadcast the information about what is on the current view using a sticky broadcast that your other activity/application can read. Or maybe your "home activity" can provide a service that you can use to ask it what the current view name is.